# Event contribution summarized by price set

Tags: civievent, contributions, reports

We use price sets for all of our events, and make extensive use of the price set header to display a "call to action" asking people to give generously/consciously/etc.  We have a variety of wording for these, and we would like to do some A/B testing and measure results.

What I would like to do is use database queries or the Pivot Report extension or even Google Data Studio to create a view showing how effective a particular price set is.  (The price set is a proxy for the call to action.)

I'm having a hard time getting contribution amount per event or per price set.

- I can get total contributions, but I don't seem to have a way to link contributions to individual events.
- I can't figure out how to get the price set from event data.

Can anyone help me figure out what fields I need to link together in order to be able to get something like "sum of contributions for events by event price set"?

Thank you

Edit: 
A few more details on our use case:

- All of our events are by donation.
- We use the header portion (pre-help text) of price sets to provide a call to action, encouraging the user to make a donation or to make a larger donation.
- We have a variety of call to action text samples, and we are developing more.
- What we are looking to analyze is how effective our different call to action text samples.  Which ones drive donations up?  Which ones are less effective?  Which ones turn people off?

Definitely open to learning about other ways to manage and measure this rather than using price set help text.

Comment: have you considered and rejected using 'campaigns' to differentiate A from B?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I'm not sure CiviCampaign applies but I'm only familiar with it at a cursory level. We are looking for feedback on the effectiveness of the text that shows up right before users decide how much to contribute/donate. We use the price set header for this.  I should mention that all our events are by donation, so the text right above the price field is the last thing they see before deciding how much to donate for an event.

Comment: just because campaign gives you an easy entity to do analysis, search, reports etc

Answer (score 1):

There’s a custom search available in CiviCRM called Price Set Details for Event Participants which may be of use for your enquiry.

Search > Custom Searches > Price Set Details for Event Participants

/civicrm/contact/search/custom?csid=9&reset=1

This search allows you to filter on an event and also gives you an option to export your results.